# DockPanelSuite - saving documents

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

In `DocumentsPanel` I have a few open forms, each of them is of another kind. How do I save the files that were open in a loop.

In this case, this works.

```
   using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter ("files.txt"))
         {

             foreach (FormEditor doc in dockPanel1.Documents)
             {
                     file.WriteLine (doc.SuperFileName);
             }
          }
   file.Close ();
```

However, if a second `FormBrowser` is opened in the panel, error pops up when you try to save the documents. The error is stated below:

```
    Unable to cast object of type 'App1.FormBrowser' to type 'App1.FormEditor'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very unclear about what is asked, and very unclear about the classes used in the code.

From observation, both `FormEditor` and `FormBrowser` are `Document` in your `DocumentsPanel`, and they would be listed in `Documents` property of `DocumentsPanel` instance, in your case is `dockPanel1`, if they exist.

Therefore, when you want to access a document and save it, you need to verify if the document is in the correct type, i.e. if it's in `FormEditor`. A simple fix could be:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter ("files.txt"))
{
    foreach (var doc in dockPanel1.Documents)
    {
        var fileEditor = doc as FormEditor;

        if (fileEditor != null)
        {
            file.WriteLine (doc.SuperFileName);
        }
    }

    file.Close();
}
```